# How can I set the dash length in a matplotlib contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making some contour plots in matplotlib and the length of the dashes are too long. The dotted line also doesn't look good. I'd like to manually set the length of the dash. I can set the exact dash length when I'm making a simple plot using plt.plot(), however I cannot figure out how to do the same thing with a contour plot.

I think that the following code should work, but I get the error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 80, in draw_path_collection
    offset_position)
TypeError: failed to obtain the offset and dashes from the linestyle
```

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do, adapted from the MPL examples:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

plt.figure()

CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, 6, colors='k',linestyles='dashed')

for c in CS.collections:
    c.set_dashes([2,2])

plt.show()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Almost.

It's:

```
for c in CS.collections:
    c.set_dashes([(0, (2.0, 2.0))])
```

If you had put a `print c.get_dashes()` there, you would have found out (it's what I did).

Perhaps the definition of the line style has changed a bit, and you were working from an older example.

The [collections documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html) has this to say:

> - set_dashes(ls)
>
>   alias for set_linestyle
> - set_linestyle(ls)
>
>   Set the linestyle(s) for the collection.
>
>   ACCEPTS: [‘solid’ | ‘dashed’, ‘dashdot’, ‘dotted’ | (offset, on-off-dash-seq) ]

So in `[(0, (2.0, 2.0))]`, 0 is the offset, and then the tuple is the on-off repeating pattern.

Comment: Thanks so much! I tired the (offset,(on,off)) format as well, but I hadn't realized that I needed the parentheses inside of the square brackets. My plots look awesome now. You just made my day. Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question, I had to deal with it and the current answer is not valid anymore. A better approach is to use `plt.rcParams['lines.dashed_style'] = [2.0, 2.0]` before your plot.

Comment: Is this a matplotlib 3 change? The previous answer still works for me, with MPL version 2.2.2. Also, I had to change `lines.dashed_style` to `lines.dashed_pattern` for this to work.

Comment: @DanHickstein The problem rises if you want to save an eps format.

Comment: Gotcha. Does the `dashed_style` versus `dashed_pattern` also change with eps format?

Comment: @DanHickstein Yes, I was trying to use the on-off pattern with `dashed_style` and it didn't work, so `dashed_style` should be only one of the default ones, then `dashed_pattern` can use the on-off format.