# change dash style of negative values in a default contour - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am trying to plot contours with matplotlib and I have negative values in the data and I want them to be dashed(which matplotlib does by default) however, I want to (1) control the dash style (on,off) and (2) change the color for the negative contours alone. I tried the answer in link: [How can I set the dash length in a matplotlib contour plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434426/how-can-i-set-the-dash-length-in-a-matplotlib-contour-plot)

But this sets all the lines in the contour to dashes which I do not want. I need to hack the negative contour line styles alone!

A part of my code:

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

matplotlib.rcParams['contour.negative_linestyle']= 'dashed'

CS = ax1.contour(xi, yi, W_t, levels=levels, colors='k', linewidths=0.05)

for c in CS.collections:
    c.set_dashes([(0, (2.0, 2.0))])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop though the line collections created by the `CS` object and for any non solid lines (from `get_linetype` with value `[(None, None)]`) set them however you want. As a minimal example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab


#Dummy data
delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)


CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, 20, colors='k')

for line in CS.collections:
    if line.get_linestyle() == [(None, None)]:
        print("Solid Line")
    else:
        line.set_linestyle([(0, (12.0, 3.0))])
        line.set_color('red')

plt.show()
```